# Django forms ChoiceField. My select don't show options

Tags: django, django-forms

I just start learn Django but I can't find any simple example without using database. I found one, but when I tried do this same on my project...this just don't work. I need help because now I have no idea what's wrong.

forms.py

```
MY_CHOICES = (
('1', 'Option 1'),
('2', 'Option 2'),
('3', 'Option 3'),
)

class MyTestForm(forms.Form):
  my_choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MY_CHOICES)
```

views.py

```
def my_view(request):
    form = MyTestForm()
    return render_response('/home/.../test.html',{'form': form})
```

test.html

```
<div>
    <select>
    {% for choice in form.my_choice_field %}
        <option>{{choice.1}}</option>

    </select>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

And this just show empty drop-down list.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: If your real example is as simple as the code above, you might not need to loop through the choices. Using `{{ form.my_choice_field }}` might do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `form.my_choice_field.choices` not `form.my_choice_field`

```
<div>
    <select>
    {% for choice in form.fields.my_choice_field.choices %}
        <option>{{choice.1}}</option>
    {% endfor %}    
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @A.Pie there was mess up with select tag. Which @LudwikTrammer fixed. It was befor `{% endfor %}`. Did you apply that?

Comment: What about using `{{ form.my_choice_field }}` instead of this whole `div` as @Alasdair suggested?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is to use `{{ form.my_choice_field }}`, and let Django take care of rendering the choice field for you.

If you really need to render the field manually, you can access the choices via the bound field's `field` attribute.

```
<select>
{% for choice in form.my_choice_field.field.choices %}
    <option value="{{ choice.0 }}">{{choice.1}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

I wasn't able to find a reference for this in the docs, so I don't know whether or not it's a documented API.